# Microsoft Azure Notification Hub Timeout Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, notifications

We have a project that needs to notify a user on her/his mobile app. Using azure as the backend, we use a **notification hub** resource to achieve that. A timeout issue is triggered (from time to time) from the backend when more than 4-5 users are supposed to receive that push:

> the request has timed out after 60000 milliseconds. The successful 
>   completion of the request cannot be determined. Additional queries 
>   should be made to determine whether or not the operation has succeeded"

this is the code I use to connect to our notification hub resource:

`var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHub"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHubPath"]);`

`var allRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0).ConfigureAwait(false);`

and the timeout exception occurs at that line:

`var allRegistrations = await hub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Somehow, the push notification does work with 1 or 2 registered devices. Has anyone encountered such problem? Note that there is no error logged on the notification hub

Answer (score 0):

That problem disappeared when we opted not to use the free plan for that resource